# Create two partial php.ini files

Tags: php, php.ini

I want to two split php.ini into two files so that I can move important entries to a new file. I think it is a *.ini* file so, any rule for creating partial .ini files will also apply to it. Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

Comment: I seriously doubt that the PHP Group would allow something like this.  I see a serious security issue with something like this, that could take a partially compromised server, and give total and complete control to a hacker.

Comment: I just want to classify important settings(mainly extensions) that are changed often in to a different file so that making change become easy for them.

Comment: Your welcome to direct this towards a dedecated PHP Community, but a feature like this is unlikely, because of the security implications.

Comment: @Ramhound I am unable to find dedecated PHP Community. I tried looking here and there but with no luck. I've also visited http://php.net/support.php I think may be php doesn't support this. But, Apache support partial hhtpd.conf